# Change cursor on legend after disabling click

Tags: javascript, html, charts, highcharts

How do i change the cursor to 'default' instead of using 'pointer'?

I disabled my graph using this:

```
plotOptions: {
    line: {
        events: {
           legendItemClick: function () {
               return false;
           }
        }
     }
 }
```

But the cursor is the pointer cursor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that the simplest way is using `itemStyle` and set cursor as default.

```
legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        borderWidth: 0,
        itemStyle: {
            'cursor': 'default'
        }
    },
```

Example:
- http://jsfiddle.net/fc8vmarp/1/

Comment: Better answer than mine... :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a CSS class `hover` and define the behavior when this class is hovered

```
.hover:hover {
   cursor: default;
}
```

Once you created your graph, you can set `.hover` to the DOM element you want to change the cursor on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML in your data labels as it seems you cannot change the style of the legend with Highcharts options [**edit : I'm wrong => `itemStyle` as Sebastian Bochan has mentioned in its answer**].

Here is an example : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vuh99Lv5/2/)

```
    series: [{
        name: '<span style="cursor:default;">Tokyo</span>',
        marker: {
            symbol: 'square'
        },
        data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, {
            y: 26.5,
            marker: {
                symbol: 'url(https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/sun.png)'
            }
        }, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]

    }, {
        name: '<span style="cursor:default;">London</span>',
        marker: {
            symbol: 'diamond'
        },
        data: [{
            y: 3.9,
            marker: {
                symbol: 'url(https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/snow.png)'
            }
        }, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
    }]
```